# Android - Https connection to a .NET WCF Service gives SSLException: "No peer certificate"

Tags: android, json, wcf, exception, ssl

**[SOLVED] - See below**

I've been getting an exception when trying to get some JSON data from my REST enabled WCF Service, in Android 2.2 over a HTTPS connection . I then noticed something very strange happening.
When running the application on my phone it worked great and it would get beautiful JSON data back. However when running the application on my the emulator, it crashed as soon as the "httpclient.execute(request)" was executed, giving an SLLException: no peer certificate. 
This being especially strange because my WCF Service had a valid RapidSSL signed certificate (CA). Plus I made sure Client certificates weren't needed inside my IIS. (Also this function wasn't running on the UIThread!, it was running on a separate thread.)

My code:

```
    public Object getJSON(String URL, HashMap<String, String> parameters, String METHOD, String TAG) {
    try {
        this.TAG = TAG;
        // Send GET request to <service>/METHOD?params
        //Target API(8) for AndroidHttpClient and Target API(5) for DefaultHttpClient
        AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
        String params = "?";
        if(parameters != null){
            for (Entry<String, String> para : parameters.entrySet()) {
                params = params + (String)para.getKey() + "=" + (String)para.getValue() + "&";
            }
            params = params.substring(0, params.length() - 1);
            Log.i("U's n P's", params);//Username and password check
        }

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL + METHOD + params);
        Log.i(TAG, request.getRequestLine().toString());
        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);//Crashes here
        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

        // Read response data into buffer
        char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
        InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
        reader.read(buffer);
        stream.close();
```

Now I've tried searching for a solution, however basically no solution fitted this situation.

**[SOLUTION]**

My emulator was running through a snapshot since I edited the hosts file so I didn't need to set my service up in a DNS. Now here comes the catch, since I ran it through a snapshot every time. The date was set to OCT 24 2012 with time 18:48 in the emulator. I then realized the date I validated the certificate was OCT 27 2012 with time 14:45. Apparently the "get time from  the internet" option DOESN'T work on the emulator. This made my httpclient throw the "No peer certificate" exception since it technically didn't have a validated certificate in the emulator. The sad part is that when you search for a solution to this exception with keywords as "android" or "https android wcf", you only get results of people with problems relating to *self signed certificates*.

**TL;DR: Apparently in the future validated certificates don't get accepted.**

Comment: Nice for finding this out yourself. I tend to read some confusion in your _"apparently"_, but it's logical: a certificate is valid from X until Y. If the current time lies outside that period according to a certain machine, the certificate is deemed invalid on that machine.

Comment: You should answer your question and mark it as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Arcshade.

My emulator was running through a snapshot since I edited the hosts file so I didn't need to set my service up in a DNS. Now here comes the catch, since I ran it through a snapshot every time. The date was set to OCT 24 2012 with time 18:48 in the emulator. I then realized the date I validated the certificate was OCT 27 2012 with time 14:45. Apparently the "get time from the internet" option DOESN'T work on the emulator. This made my httpclient throw the "No peer certificate" exception since it technically didn't have a validated certificate in the emulator. The sad part is that when you search for a solution to this exception with keywords as "android" or "https android wcf", you only get results of people with problems relating to self signed certificates.